# How to get email address of shared file user (Google Drive api PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the role and email address of persons whom I shared my google drive file.

```
//this->drive is object of service_drive
$permissions = $this->drive->permissions->listPermissions($file->id);
foreach ($permissions->getPermissions() as $permission){
 echo $permission['emailAddress'];
}
```

this is returning me null, is there anyway I can know completely about the person or at least email address and his role ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get info as the email, name or role of the people you share your files with using the [***Permissions: list***](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) endpoint. ***Try this API***  can help you to play around with the info you want to retrieve using the ***fields*** parameters, which uses [partial responses](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response).

[image]

Translating the explanation  from above to PHP code, this is what you would need to do:

```
// Build a parameters array
$parameters = array();
// Specify what fields you want 
$parameters['fields'] = "permissions(*)";
// Call the endpoint 
$permissions = $service->permissions->listPermissions($file->id, $parameters);
// print results
foreach ($permissions->getPermissions() as $permission){
    echo $permission['emailAddress'];
}
```

Comment: your foreach statement clarified the best method to retrieve all the permission attributes - thanks

Comment: talent permissions(*) is what I need for get info, how you know that, because indocument I not found it. https://imgur.com/a/acQRWpV